# Django DRF Serializer fields required conditionally

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer which looks like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    lat = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
    lng = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
```

I want to make sure that if a request comes with the 'lat' field, the 'lng' field will be mandatory and vice versa.

I can do it with validate function but believe there is a better way of doing that.

Comment: What about changing `required` parameter to `True` for both fields ?, (`lat = serializers.FloatField(required=True)`)

Comment: But I need an option that both do not exist. So if a user send lat only it should fail, lng only should fail both if he didn't provide lat or lng that should be ok.

Comment: If so, I think the best and only option is to define a validate() method or generic Validator class

Answer (score 12):

You should use the serializer `validate` method to check this.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lat = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
    lng = serializers.FloatField(required=False)

    def validate(self, data):
        if not data['lat'] and not data['lng']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("They are both required.")
    return data
```

Reference: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation

Comment: Notice I wrote that I know I can do it with validate function and I search for a better approach because for a complicated serializer with many options I don't see how this scale and it become very unreadable. also, notice that you have a problem with your solution because it does not support the option to exclude both (they are not required as a couple, but as long as there is one of them both are required) this shows exactly why there must be another solution :)

Comment: Doesn't it produce a `KeyError`?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example of how to write a mixin to Serializer, which will allow **conditionally required fields**. See docstring for an example

```
class ConditionalRequiredMixin:
    """
    Adds flexibility to required fields by setting up `conditional_required_fields`

    For example
        conditional_required_fields = [
        ('is_blind': {
            'condition': False,
            'required_fields': ['clock', 'naming', 'alternate_trail_making', 'cube_drawing']
        }),
        ('is_blind': {
            'condition': True,
            'required_fields': ['clock2', 'naming2',]
        })
    ]

    If is_blind will be False -> fields specified in required_fields will be required

    """
    REQUIRED_MSG = ['Field is required']
    conditional_required_fields = []

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        for master_field, conditions in self.conditional_required_fields:
            master_field_value = attrs.get(master_field)
            condition = conditions['condition']
            if not isinstance(condition, str) and isinstance(condition, collections.Iterable):
                trigger = master_field_value in condition
            else:
                trigger = master_field_value == condition

            if trigger:
                additional_required_fields = conditions['required_fields']
                absent_fields = [f for f in additional_required_fields if attrs.get(f) is None]
                if absent_fields:
                    error_dict = {f: self.REQUIRED_MSG for f in absent_fields}
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(error_dict)
        return attrs
```